# How to get rake to use the 'integration' directory instead of 'requests' for integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rake, integration-testing

I'd like to keep my integration tests in spec/integration. However when I generate one of these rake creates a spec/requests directory.

Is there a way to point the generator at another directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using the requests directory - realizing that my preference for calling the directory 'integration' wasn't worth the effort seeking this out.

It might be poor form to mark this as the answer.. let me know

Answer (score 1):

You may modify the spec_helper. Add capybara in your rspec configuration will suffice for instance.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL, type: :integration
end
```

Then you could add your own helpers:

```
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.with_options example_group: { file_path: /\bspec\/integration\// } do |integration|
      integration.include SomeIntegrationHelper
    end
 end
```

Comment: thanks for your response - but this doesn't look like it will make the rspec generator dump new tests in the integration directory - maybe this isn't possible?

Comment: Unfortunately for what I saw the dir is hardcoded:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/rspec/integration/integration_generator.rb